# How to redirect a page to the custom location after form validation?

Tags: comments, redirection, navigation

I have a form with comment section. when the comment is given as empty it redirects to the page called /comment/reply. I have to change it to my custom path. how can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really do it in validator. Redirect in submit handler, with code like:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = 'comment/reply';
```

For more details of form redirecting [consult official documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
mymodule_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['#action'] = "my/path";
}
```

An empty string will mean the form doesn't redirect.